# Jsoup - Android: Can't get style attribute from class

Tags: android, jsoup

So I'm working on a webapp and I need to get style attribute from an `i class` and extract background url from it to use it in app...

Here's my `AsyncTask` method:

```
public class GetImageBruh extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Element> {

    protected Element doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        Element result = null;
        ChatScreen.this.syncCookies();
        int i = 0;

        while (true) {
            int tries = i + ChatScreen.REQUEST_STORAGE;
            if (i >= ChatScreen.MAX_RETRY || result != null) {
                return result;
            }
            Log.i("GetImageBruh", "doInBackground: Processing... Trial: " + tries);
            Log.i("GetImageBruh", "Trying: " + ChatScreen.this.url);
            Element notification = ChatScreen.this.getElement(ChatScreen.this.url);
            if (notification != null) {
                result = notification;
            }
            i = tries;
        }
        return result;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Element result) {
        String imageUrl;

        String style = result.select("div._4g34").select("i[aria-label=" + ChatScreen.this.friendName + "]").attr(AnalyticsEvents.PARAMETER_LIKE_VIEW_STYLE);

        try {
            imageUrl = style.substring(style.indexOf("https://"), style.indexOf(")")).replace("\"", BuildConfig.FLAVOR);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            imageUrl = null;
        }
        Log.d("GetImageBruh", "Style: " + imageUrl);
    }
}

private Element getElement(String connectUrl) {
    Element element = null;
    try {
        element = Jsoup.connect(connectUrl).header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch").userAgent(this.savedPreferences.getString("webview_user_agent", System.getProperty("http.agent"))).timeout(600000).cookie("m.facebook.com/messages/read/", CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie("m.facebook.com/messages/read")).get();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Cookie sync problem occurred");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return element;
}
```

Here `friendName` equals to something like `John Smith`...

HTML structure is something like:

```
<div class="_4g34">
<div class="di">
<a class="profilePic">
<i class="img profpic" style="background.....">
</i>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

What is getting printed is "null"...
What I'm doing wrong in this code?

Comment: Basically you are asking to debug code without all data, e.g. site which you use. Probably you can look here https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html ?

Comment: @Divers it's facebook site... I need to get profile pic of user in messages screen... In my code mysite.com is actually m.facebook.com/messages/read . I'm trying to get image from past two days.. I tried to print the "result.select("div._4g34")" and it is printing HTML code which is fair.. but "aria-label" from "i" class is printing null... Oh and the "url" string which is being passed to getElement equals to any valid conversation url..

Comment: First: web scraping without permission violates fb's ToS: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php Second: fb relies heavily on javascript, so jsoup is not the right tool for grabbing the page. Use a `webView` and maybe parse with jsoup or do your modifications with javascript in the `webView`.